# Matlab read/use byte array without creating a file

Tags: matlab, byte

I have an array of bytes (which represents e.g. a CSV file) which are coming from C# in Matlab and I want to load this now without creating an temporary file.

Is there a possibility to do that? All methods I found are only taking filenames or requires that they will write it into a file.

Thanks!

Comment: Expect that on the server where it will run we don't have any rights to create files..

Comment: You have an array of bytes, but where? Internal memory? Is it a variable already in matlab? If it is in matlab, you could use `textscan` to convert a csv-like character vector to individual values.

Comment: Yes, it is a variable with `uint8`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I made a small csv file consisting of 8 values. Read it as uint8 it in matlab and used textscan to retrieve the original 8 values.

```
orgdat =    [132   231   334   234;   132   432   423   334];
csvwrite('temp.csv',orgdat);
fid = fopen('temp.csv');
dat = fread(fid,inf,'*uint8');fclose(fid);
cell2mat(textscan(char(dat),'%f,%f,%f,%f'))
>>
ans =
   132   231   334   234
   132   432   423   334
```

Or if you just want to scan for numbers:

```
result = cell2mat(textscan(char(dat),'%f','Delimiter',','))
>>
result =

   132   231   334   234   132   432   423   334
```

To reshape it you could look for the number of rows and reshape

```
rows = sum(dat==10)+(dat(end)~=10);
reshape(result,[],rows)'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want. This is creating a file! And I don't have the data in clear text, I have them in bytes[]

Comment: That's why it is an example. I create a variable called `dat` that has bytes[] in it (32 bytes to be exact). Then in one line I convert it back to the original values. So I read a csv that is encoded as bytes[] variable. I thought that is what you wanted, if not, please make your question clear with an example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry I went a little bit to fast over your example, brain didn't worked that well after lunch :D I just have tow more question, 1. you are using '%f%f%f%f' because we have 4 columns in one row, correct? What do I do if I don't know about the columns size? 2. What if it contains characters e.g. 1.64E-07?

Comment: correct. Basically you are sorting on commas (byte value 44) and returns (byte value 10). What you could do is split the byte[] based on value 10, and then count how many 44's you have. That +1 is the nr of columns. Scientific notation is no problem for textscan. Try `cell2mat(textscan('1.64E-07','%f'))`. It will return the right number.

Comment: The `reshapre` is not working as expected: in your example it will return me `132   334   132   423 NEWLINE 231   234   432   334` it will mix some values e.g. the last one in the first row or the first one in the second row.

Comment: Yeah. Updated the answer. It had 1-3-5-7 ; 2-4-6-8 as the order. So it took column first. You want row first, since that's how you read it in.